# Request GCD synonym to Greatest Common Divisor

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

I would like to propose a synonym for the [gcd](/questions/tagged/gcd) tag. Because a popular the Cocoa technology, Grand Central Dispatch, uses that acronym, the most common use of the [gcd](/questions/tagged/gcd) tag on Stack Overflow was in that context, even though the wiki excerpt advised against that. As a result, in another [Meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165133/propose-significant-change-in-the-definition-of-gcd-tag), I made a synonym request between [gcd](/questions/tagged/gcd) and [grand-central-dispatch](/questions/tagged/grand-central-dispatch). That was a very unpopular suggestion. Because of the vocal feedback on that suggestion, I (and others) went through Grand Central Dispatch related questions tagged with [gcd](/questions/tagged/gcd) and retagged them as [grand-central-dispatch](/questions/tagged/grand-central-dispatch).

So, I would like to now suggest a new [gcd](/questions/tagged/gcd) synonym of [greatest-common-divisor](/questions/tagged/greatest-common-divisor). While that's not necessarily a synonym that resonates with me personally, I think it's clear that this is more popular than the proposed synonym to [grand-central-dispatch](/questions/tagged/grand-central-dispatch). I'd also suggest that we delete the [proposed synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/grand-central-dispatch/synonyms) (first proposed Nov 2010) between [grand-central-dispatch](/questions/tagged/grand-central-dispatch) and [gcd](/questions/tagged/gcd).

Leaving [gcd](/questions/tagged/gcd) without a synonym will only be an ongoing source of confusion. It's short and ambiguous. I think the best way to avoid continual misuse is to define a synonym. Clearly the use of the wiki excerpt was not sufficient.

Comment: "[greatest-common-divisor] is more popular than the proposed synonym to grand-central-dispatch" It boggles the mind.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Yeah, as a Cocoa guy, I'm a little surprised, too. But look at the universal response I received to my [other proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165133/propose-significant-change-in-the-definition-of-gcd-tag). Personally, I care less about what we define the synonym to, than I do that we define a synonym to avoid ongoing conflicting use of the [tag:gcd] tag.

Comment: There are obviously thousands of useful programming questions about finding the greatest common divisor. Grand Central Dispatch is certainly too niche...</sarcasm> There are probably 2 useful programming questions about greatest common divisors...asked thousands of times by students.

Comment: 36 questions for the GDC tag? I say - retag those and then nuke it from orbit, so we wil never hear of the acronym again

Comment: Kudos, by the way, for the editing effort. I noticed something going on the other day and wondered if you had organized it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completed, after confirming with another moderator.